# .bacpac file from "Export Data-Tier Application" to Azure - local storage requirements?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I have a large 350GB database (local server) I need to create a .bacpac file of.  We're looking at using Azure Blob storage as the target, since there is only 49GB of free space remaining on the local servers.  When going through the dialogs, it asks where to put the temporary file... does this mean the .bacpac file is generate entirely on the local system before being sent to Azure?

Comment: Is there some way you can avoid creating a .bacpac of a 350GB database?  That's going to be painful.  Can you use a regular backup instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to export the database from the SSMS to the Azure blob storage

- On Export Settings Page you need to select **Save to Azure** option. You must connect to an Azure container in order to validate this option. It Creates a BACPAC file in a specified Azure container.
- Be aware that using this option requires selecting a local directory for the temporary file. Keep in mind that once the process is finished, the temporary file will still be there where it was created.
- During the export process, SSMS generates a temporary `.bacpac` file on your local system, as specified by the local directory you provide.
- After the operation completes and the `.bacpac` file is transferred to Azure storage, the temporary file will remain in the specified local directory unless you manually delete it.

***To ensure a successful export, make sure to have enough free space in the specified local directory to accommodate the temporary .bacpac file.***

Reference: [Export a Data-tier Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver16#Export_settings)